# How do I check if all elements in a list are equal?

Tags: common-lisp

This is what I got so far, but it is only comparing the first element with the second element. So if I evaluate this ?(check ‘(a a a a)) it should return true but if I evaluate ?(check ‘(a a a b)) it should return Nil

```
(defun check (lista)
(cond
((null lista)'())
((equal (car lista)(cadr lista))cdr lista)
(t(check (cdr lista)))))
```

Comment: Please check the indentation and the syntax of your code. In the second `cond` a pair of parenthesis are missing, I guess.

Comment: The parenthesis missing are in the cdr lista,adding the parenthesis will request for cdr lista be a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Indent your code for readability
- Check the case where the list only has one element
- You call your function recursively when first and second elements are distinct, but in that case you don't need it since the property is already known to be false.

Your attempt is almost good you only put the recursive call in a wrong place. Equality is transitive so you only need to compare each element with its successor and see if the property holds for the sublist. I would personally write it as follow :

```
(defun all-equal-p (list)
  (or (null (rest list)) ;; singleton/empty
      (and (equalp (first list)
                   (second list))
           (all-equal-p (rest list)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this the most idiomatic way but I would start with something like this

```
CL-USER> (let* ((list '(a a a a))
                (first-element (first list)))
           (every (lambda (x) (equal x first-element)) list))
T
CL-USER> (let* ((list '(a a a b))
                (first-element (first list)))
           (every (lambda (x) (equal x first-element)) list))
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use this as reference when I get to the point of using lambda expressions, I don't really understand lambda expressions yet

Answer (score 5):

Exercises aside, the most concise form to check this would be

```
(every #'eql list (rest list))
```

`Every` takes a function and applies it to one element of each of the following sequences, which may be any number that the function accepts.  So, this invocation compares each two consecutive elements.